# Why can binomial distribution for a binomial random variable S ...

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

Why can binomial distribution for a binomial random variable S be approximated by a continuous normal distribution, in regards to convergence in probability and convergence in distribution?

We did not have time to cover this in lecture this week and it is one of my homework questions. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: For convergence in distribution, take the characteristic function (or moment generating function) of your binomial random variable, make a suitable location and scale adjustment, and show convergence to the characteristic function (or mgf) of a normal random variable.